# change field value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have hidden field like

```
<div class="hiddenFields">
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="www.test.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="params_id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
</div>
```

is there any way to select RET from jquery and change its value
please let me know how to do that.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to target element by its name attribute:

```
$('[name=RET]').val('newval')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible. you can use [attribute-equals-selecto](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selecto/) try this:-

for set value use `$('[name="RET"]').val("new value");`

for get value use `var ret=$('[name="RET"]').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like. I have removed input `type = hidden` in demo so that you can see changed value in the output section

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input[name='RET'").val("mytest.php");
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfndn8d6/1/)